# How to get the ID attribute of a Datepicker Input?

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I have a series of `daterangepicker` input fields, each assigned with an ID.
How can I get the attribute ID for each input field?

Here is my main code:

```js
$('input[name="birthday"]').daterangepicker(
  {
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    minYear: 2000,
    maxYear: 2100,
    locale: localeDate,
  },
  function (start, end, label) {
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));

    var year = start.format("YYYY");
    var month = start.format("MM");
    var day = start.format("DD");
  }
);
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
$(this).attr('id') is undefined.
```

Comment: Is there an `id` attribute in the markup?

Comment: You need to add `html` code of your datepicker

Comment: obvious i have added id attribute on html input

Answer (score 1):

You need to acces the `element` attribute to get the input element

```
 $('input[name="birthday"]').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    minYear: 2000,
    maxYear: 2100,
    locale: localeDate,
}, function(start, end, label) {


   console.log( this.element.attr('id') );

    var year = start.format('YYYY');
    var month = start.format('MM');
    var day = start.format('DD');

});
```